# Is there a way to pass non-project .fs files into a command-line argument in an FSharp .exe?

Tags: f#

Let's say that I have an `exe` that has a function called `compareTwoThings`.  I'd like `compareTwoThings` to be able to take, as arguments, two directories that have identical file names in each: a `.json` and a `.fs`.  In `compareTwoThings`, I want to be able to read in each `.json` (easy-peasy) and each `.fs` file.  The contents of each `.fs` file will be known.

How can I read in each `.fs` file and use the values in those `.fs` files without them being a part of the overall project structure?  Can I?  I understand that to build a project and have the project "see" into the `.fs` files, they need to be added to the `.fsproj` file, but can I not use `open` on an external file that has a module name?

Example dir structure of the proj:

```
myProj
    |-proj
        |-compareTwoThings.fs
        |-myProj.fs
        |-myProj.fsproj
Thing1
    |-Thing1.fs
    |-Thing1.json
Thing2
    |-Thing2.fs
    |-Thing2.json
```

And ultimately, the CLI statement would be something like

```
myProj compareTwoThings [dir to Thing1] [dir to Thing2] [output dir]
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something very simple here.

**Edit**: I do not believe that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172888/f-defining-using-a-type-module-in-another-file-in-the-same-project) is related as I'm asking how to open a non-project `.fs` file.

Comment: It sounds like you want to read the .fs files and parse them (and import their functions into the execution environment).  Correct?  If so, have a look at FSharp Compiler Services. https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/

Comment: @RobertSim Correct.  Thanks for pointing out that library.  I had never heard of it.  I'll spend some time with it this morning.